# How to properly achieve toolbar transparency and blurry without system color change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here for example, this is from the native messaging app on iOS the footer bottom bar is black as the background. It doesn't have any different color, lighter than that:

[image]

Here it is nicely transparent and blurry when the message scrolls pass behind it:
[image]

I want to achieve this effect in my code, however I can't achieve this at all.
Here is an example of my app, when content is empty:
[image]

And here is with content behind it:
[image]

I see some other apps are using same technique, like the facebook messenger or signal apps.

Here is my code:

```
let toolbarBackground = UIToolbarAppearance()
toolbarBackground.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)

toolbarBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor(dynamicProvider: { traitCollection in
    return traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? 
        UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5) : UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
})

toolbarBackground.shadowColor = .clear
UIToolbar.appearance().standardAppearance = toolbarBackground
UIToolbar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = toolbarBackground
```

The part `UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)` is for light mode, and has no effect on dark mode.

Comment: It's unclear what you want that's different from what you are getting. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I want my `UIToolbar` to be black as the background, now it's off black. And I want to be transparent blurry as content is scrolled behind it, just like its in the imessage . Right now I am using `UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)` which may not be the right way? @HangarRash

Comment: If you want it to be black then make it solid black instead of transparent black. Of course you want two separate appearances. The solid black for `scrollEdgeAppearance` and transparent black for `standardAppearance`.

Comment: When I tried that, I got the toolbar black, but as soonest I scroll close to it the toolbar gets highlighted/light up and becomes transparent which is not ideal. I should just remain solid without any highlights. @HangarRash

Comment: I'm confused about what you want. Do you want it to always be solid black or should it be transparent sometimes (and if so, when exactly)?

Comment: Not sure if you have whatsapp for example, thats how my app behaves when I change it to two separate views. I want it to behave as iMessages. Its a lot easier to see when you scroll it, or on video. But yea I want it to be black solid normally and I want it to change to `UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)` when list comes to scroll view behind the toolbar @HangarRash

Comment: It would help if you posted pictures of your app's toolbar. Right now you've posted pictures of a tab bar. Also show relevant code for creating the toolbar. You tagged the question SwiftUI but you posted UIKit code.